# Combine 2 database fields

Tags: database, ip, field

Allright this is my question.

I have 1 database field posts_content with posts from hundred of peoples with this structure:

- id
- created
- text
- ip

Another database field posts_block with the ip's how i want to block

- id
- ip

How can i create a select query from field 1 to select right posts without blocks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.ip=table2.ip
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from posts_content WHERE ip <> (select ip from posts_block);
```